# CakePHP behavior not working with bindModel

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, bind, behavior

I have a model named **Users** defined as:

```
class User extends AppModel {

...

public $actsAs = array(
    'Date' => array('date_birth')
);

...
```

The **Date** **behavior** converts the field **date_birth** from iso format ('yyyy-mm-dd') to locale format ('dd/mm/yyyy').

When from my controller I do a find such as

```
$this->User->find(...)
```

the behavior works fine and the field date_birth is formatted as dd/mm/yyyy.

Now, **this is my problem**:

I have a second model called **Reviews**.

In my controller I use the **bindModel** method to create the following relationship between the two models:

Review **belongsTo** User

When I do $this->Review->find() the User info are fetched along with the Review info. But **the behavior defined in the User model is not applied** and the field date_birth is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Are you just using recursive to get your additional data, or are you using Containable (as you should be)?   I would try to verify for sure that it's not being triggered.  It might be running, but because it's an associated model the data is formatted differently and your logic might need altered.  More details here:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind

Comment: I'm not using Containable. The afterFind method in the behavior is not being called. I'll check Containable, thanks.

Comment: Also, why are you binding the Model in your Controller?  Seems like Review would always just belong to User via Model's associations.  I assume it's because you're using recursive, but once you switch your entire app to `$recursive = -1;` (in the AppModel) and use Containable to retrieve additional model data, you can also start actually setting up all your associations completely and not worrying about having to bind/unbind all the time for concern that they'll pull extra unwanted data.  So, set `$recursive -1;` and `$actsAs = array('Containable')` in your AppModel, & build all associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved the problem by changing the code in the **Behavior** so to accept fields of the form **User.date_birth**